# How to delete queue message without storing log info in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, message-queue, service-broker

I have already enabled "Service Broker" in my database. But recently I noticed that my database size is increasing day by day unexpectedly. Finally I've found out that my database size increase unexpectedly because of queue message of internal table.
The C drive is almost full, that's why I could not delete queue message from internal table. When I execute query for delete query then log file size increase accordingly, that's why I want to delete queue message without storing log.
Thanks.

[image: queue message]

Comment: Backup the transaction log instead of trying to avoid it. You can't do that anyway. In all database products, the transaction log is *THE* fundamental mechanism allowing recovery from unexpected shutdowns, committing and rolling back transactions. BTW you shouldn't be storing either data or transaction log files in the system disk.

Comment: In the common `FULL` recovery mode, transaction log entries are kept until the transaction log is backed up with a transaction log backup. If something goes wrong, the server will check the log to find any changes that haven't been applied to the data files yet, replay any committed transactions and reverse any transactions still pending. Without a safe copy you wouldn't be able to restore your database in case of error

Comment: Not need log data. Now I what to do?

Comment: For this queue message log file almost 250GB.